# React Native Modal not displaying using context and redux

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-modal

I created a custom `ModalContext.js` but my test modal does not seem to be showing when I trigger a button's `onPress`

```
// ModalContext.js
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';

const modalReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'openModal':
      return { ...state, component: action.payload };
    case 'hideModal':
      return { ...state, component: null };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const openModal = (dispatch) => (component) => {
  console.log('hey there');
  dispatch({ type: 'openModal', payload: component });
};

const hideModal = (dispatch) => () => {
  dispatch({ type: 'hideModal' });
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
  modalReducer,
  {
    openModal,
    hideModal,
  },
  { component: null }
);
```

```
// createDataContext.js
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
  const Context = React.createContext();

  const Provider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);

    const boundActions = {};
    for (let key in actions) {
      boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
    }

    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  };

  return { Context, Provider };
};
```

```
// App.js
const App = createAppContainer(navigator);

export default () => {
  return (
    <ModalProvider>
      <AuthProvider>
        <App
          ref={(navigator) => {
            setNavigator(navigator);
          }}
        />
      </AuthProvider>
    </ModalProvider>
  );
};
```

I have a button on a test screen to check if it works or not.

```
// WebViewScreen.js
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Modal, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

import { Context as ModalContext } from '../context/ModalContext';

const WebViewScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { state, openModal } = useContext(ModalContext);

  const errorModal = (
    <View>
      <Modal animationType='slide' visible={true}>
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          openModal(errorModal);
        }}
        title='button'
      />
    </>
  );
};

WebViewScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    title: navigation.getParam('title'),
  };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  view: {
    backgroundColor: '#f1f3f4',
  },
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 22,
  },
  modalView: {
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
  },
});

export default WebViewScreen;
```

It seems to actually call the function as I can see `"hey there"` on the console but no modals appear.

Comment: The best way is that define modal components in main file of your app and use redux state to show it from anywhere from app.

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies Hi, i've just updated my question with an attempt at making a `ModalContext` with a reducer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for or not but I manage my details like following.

```
class Abc { 
var1; 
var2; 
var3 = new B();
var4 = new C();
var5 = {}
var6 = [];

success = a => {
//your logic
}
}

class B {
varA;
varB;
varC = false;
}
```

I hope this is helpful.